# Dynamic role according to the environment

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm new to NestJs and Typescript, and I'm trying to use a dynamic role on Authguard, according to the environment.

I have 2 environments, QA and production, and I'm trying to segregate the controllers by teams. For example, some QA users from team 1 will be member of the respective LDAP group, similar with the prod users from the same team.

```
export enum Role {
  team1 = 'team1QA',
  team2 = 'team2QA',
}

//or

export enum Role {
  team1 = 'team1Prod',
  team2 = 'team2Prod',
}
```

I tried to create the role as following but string-based enums don't work with computed values:

```
export enum Role {
  team1 = isProdEnv ? 'team1Prod' : 'team1QA' ,
  team2 = isProdEnv ? 'team2Prod' : 'team2QA' ,
}
```

Currently, I'm using a role.enum.ts file with the QA Role, as above (similar to the NestJS docs https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization).

What options do I have? Generate a global enum at the startup according to the environment? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Those should be 4 different roles. Use `isProdEnv` to determine which role to use when you assigning the role, not when defining them.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example on how to do that?